# Angular router.navigate is not working in MatDialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have NewCategoryComponent, that has the form to get details and WarningComponent which will display when user closes the form.

On clicking close(x) icon, user will get warning message([Mat Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)), "*Are you sure you want to close?*". Then user should go to the previous route.

If my current route is `category/101/newCategory`, it should go to `category/101`. I have implemented `this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });`.

#### Problem

If i keep `this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });` in WarningComponent, it is going to `/`(root) location.
In NewCategoryComponent, it is working perfectly fine.

#### Code

**NewCategoryComponent**

```js
// new-category.component.html
<button mat-icon-button class="cancelBtn" (click)="showWarning()">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
</button>


// new-category.component.ts
showWarning(): void {
    this.matDialog.open(WarningComponent);

    // going to localhost:4200/category/101
    // this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute }); // working
}
```

**Warning Component**

```js
// warning.component.html
<button mat-raised-button class="wrnBtn stayBtn" (click)="stay()">
    <span>Stay</span>
</button>
<button mat-raised-button class="wrnBtn closeBtn" (click)="close()">
    <span>Close</span>
</button>

// warning.component.ts
constructor(
    public warningDialog: MatDialogRef<WarningComponent>,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
  
close() {
    this.warningDialog.close();
    this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute }); // not working properly
}
stay() {
    this.warningDialog.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go this route "category/101" from  this "category/101/newCategory". then do the following:
this.router.navigate(['/category/101']);
assuming category has no parent route. Let me know if it works..

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mohammad. I can't hard code the `101` in the router, as it is an `id` which is generated based on the category i click. so if i am in `category/102` and click back, i would end up in `category/101` instead of `category/102`

Comment: I don't understand clearly. can you please write elaborately

Comment: you might want to check this out, to understand what i am trying to explain. 
[route params](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

It looks the issue is already reported in [Github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13803), and I cannot found any solution for that so far.

But I have created a workaround, which is not ideal but works with Angular 8.

So, for your case:

current url: /category/101/newCategory

destinaton url : /category/101

```
// 1. solve the issue that Typescript thinks _routeState doesn't exist on Router
// we have to cast Router to any type to avoid compilation error
let r = this.router as any;

// 2. get current absolute url
let url = r.routerState.root._routerState.snapshot.url;

// 3. remove everything after the last forward slash
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

this.router.navigate([url]);
```

The jist is to have access to the absolute path and after just get rid of the last bit of the url to navigate to the parent comoponent.